# C# array returns value by foreach, not by array index

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, split

I have below code:

```
String[] splititemcol;
String[] splititem;
String singlestring;
while (reader.Read())
{
    splititemcol = reader.GetValue(2).ToString().Split((char)16); //split each item
    for (int i = 0; i < splititemcol.Count(); i++)
    {
        splititem = splititemcol[i].ToString().Split((char)14);
        resultstr.Append("<tr><td>" + splititem[0] + "</td><td>");
        singlestring = "";
        for(int k=0;k<splititem.Count();k++)
        {
            if(k==2)
            {
                singlestring = splititem[k].ToString();
                break;
            }
        }
        resultstr.Append(singlestring + "</td></tr>");
    }
}
```

In above code I could get value of 3rd `splititem`.

```
String[] splititemcol;
String[] splititem;
String singlestring;
while (reader.Read())
{
    splititemcol = reader.GetValue(2).ToString().Split((char)16); //split each item
    for (int i = 0; i < splititemcol.Count(); i++)
    {
        splititem = splititemcol[i].ToString().Split((char)14);
        resultstr.Append("<tr><td>" + splititem[0] + "</td><td>");
        singlestring =splititem[2].ToString();
        resultstr.Append(singlestring + "</td></tr>");
    }
}
```

In above code I try to get value of 3rd `splititem` only by array index i.e. without `foreach`.

But it throws `Index was outside the bounds` error on line 9 as below.

```
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
```

When I test `splititem.Count` it shows 4.

**EDIT:**

I manually store every value of the array in variable as like this and all are return values. So I come to the conclusion that either we have to iterate array by for loop or this script is stuck due to my strange delimiter in the strings (character 14).

```
String[] splititemcol;
String[] splititem;
String singlestring;
String item="";
String weight="";
String quantity="";
String amount="";
while (reader.Read())
{
    splititemcol = reader.GetValue(2).ToString().Split((char)16); //split each item
    for (int i = 0; i < splititemcol.Count(); i++)
    {
        splititem = splititemcol[i].ToString().Split((char)14);
        resultstr.Append("<tr><td>" + splititem[0] + "</td><td>");
        singlestring = "";
        for(int k=0;k<splititem.Count();k++)
        {
                        if (k == 0)
                            item = splititem[k].ToString();
                        else if (k == 1)
                            weight = splititem[k].ToString();
                        else if (k == 2)
                            quantity = splititem[k].ToString();
                        else if (k == 3)
                            amount = splititem[k].ToString();
        }
        resultstr.Append(weight + "</td><td>" + quantity + "</td><td>" + amount + "</td></tr>");
    }
}
```

Thank you for all you guys try to give solution in this issue.

Comment: that means `splititem[2]` doesn't exists.

Comment: could you explain it?

Comment: It means that array `splititem` has only up to 2 elements, not 3

Comment: Actually it means `splititem[2]` exists for *some* reader results, but *not for all* of them.

Comment: Dhay, it may say count 4 for the first item but i bet the error is not on the first item, its probably further down the line that means either a folder item or other content type doesn't have a third field.

Comment: Convert the split items to a list and iterate the list, that way you'll never go out-of-bounds.

Answer (score 1):

That means `splititem[2]` doesn't exists. In your first case you have the below condition which considering only lines which will have `splititem[2]` but in second case you are trying to access index 2 directly resulting in exception

```
                    if(k==2)
                    {
                        singlestring = splititem[k].ToString();
                        break;
                    }
```

Comment: @Dhay have you tested ALL splititem.Counts in your `splititemcol`

Comment: @Dhay, point is, not all lines from `splititemcol[]` wil have those many arguments

Comment: Yes. Every field has 4.

Comment: @Dhay thats good, then just write `System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(splititem.Length == 4, "Oops, I screwed up");` right after the assignment (`splititem = splititemcol[i].ToString().Split((char)14);`). It will help you making sure everything is like you expect it to be.

Answer (score 0):

Compare this (from first snippet):

```
if(k==2)
{
    singlestring = splititem[k].ToString();
    break;
}
```

with this (from the second snippet):

```
 singlestring =splititem[2].ToString();
```

In the first case you make a check and provided that `k==2` is true you read the corresponding value. That misses from the second case and nobody guarantees that `splititem` has a Length of 3.